# БЭМ как собирать merged-бандлы

Tags: html, node.js, html5, вёрстка, бэм

Добрый день! Столкнулся с проблемой при попытке собрать merged-бандл. Делал как описано здесь https://ru.bem.info/toolbox/enb/enb-bem-techs/build-merged-bundle/, пробовал по разному крутить, использовать другие модули вместо тех что в примере, но без толку. Скрипт нормально проходит по простым бандлам, находит decl-ы, ну и дальше вроде нормально отрабатывает но decl в папке merged не создается и, естественно вылетает ошибка при сборке, потому что собирать то и нечего. При этом сама папка создается.
С БЭМ только знакомлюсь, как и со сборщиком, возможно лучше для сбора ассетсов для всех бандлов в один использовать совсем другой инструмент или же подходить иначе?

Comment: В общем проблема разрешилась. Поменяли project-stab (по ходу в инструкции не та версия какая-то) а дальше помогла вот эта темка https://ru.bem.info/forum/974/ и..... О чудо! Всё отработало как нужно.... Правда не минифицировало js и css, но то уже вообще не проблема и даже если не разберемся как исправить, то минифицируем отдельно да и всё.
Надеюсь кому-то еще пригодится